# Adding filterable attribute to layered navigation, invisible on product page

Tags: attributes, layered-navigation, filter, search

I know that you can add a drop down to your product pages with attributes like color and size.

What I would like to do is make some products on my site filterable through layered navigation without anything appearing on the product page.

**For example.**

```
Size: Full sized (100)
      Half sized (25).
```

> Is there a way to do this through vanilla Magento? or
>
> does it require some custom coding/module?

Answer (score 0):

Set `Use In Layered Navigation` for the attribute in question? It's in `Front-end Properties`